# Add two bars on page bottom

Tags: sapui5

I want to add 2 bars in the bottom area of a page (a normal bar with buttons and another bar with the current navigation path).
I used SplitApp but I forgot the current location when I navigated the menu on the left.
[image]
I want another bar over the black bar but I can't add 2 bars in the footer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to add two bars to the footer.  https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Page.html#setFooter
The setFooter method of sap.m.Page only accepts sap.m.IBar as parameter.

There are APIs of sap.m.Bar. You can define Controls in left and right position to meet your requirements.

```
Aggregations
   contentLeft : sap.ui.core.Control[]
   contentMiddle : sap.ui.core.Control[]
   contentRight : sap.ui.core.Control[]
```

Comment: You may also try to extend the sap.m.IBar to your own control and change the renderer, but the simplest is to go with Allen's answer